# Getting value from dropdownbox's input in model

Tags: codeigniter, model, view

i have a dropdown box named **f_chapter** and id is also **f_chapter** . As it have different choices when user selects one of the choices , in model i can get the input by calling $this->input->post('f_chapter') . But i don't need this , I need the value of  the input .

example:

```
<option value=""></option>
<option value="id1">Chapter1</option>
<option value="id2">Chapter5</option>
...................
```

Now if i want to grab the value in my model how should i get? as i don't need chapter1 ,chapter5......... rather i need id1,id2 ......... as these are my primary key ,i need them for database query.Please help . Advance thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the values by default without any change. I mean you will only get id1,id2,.. not chapter 1,2..

Comment: love u man , u r so helpful. thanks a lot.@ Nish,  if i have ability to increase your reputation i would do it.